# How do I define custom function to be called from IPython's prompts?

Tags: configuration, ipython

I had an old ipy_user_conf.py in which I included a simple function into the user namespace like this:

```
import IPython.ipapi
ip = IPython.ipapi.get()

def myfunc():
   ...

ip.user_ns['myfunc'] = myfunc
```

Then, I could use myfunc in the prompt.

However, I updated to IPython 0.12.1 and now the ip_user_conf.py does not work. I haven't seen how to translate such a custom function for prompts to the new configuration model.

Which is the way to do this?

Best regards,
Manuel.

UPDATE: Changed the subject to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading a bit of the documentation (and peeking at the source code for leads) I found the solution for this problem.

Simply now you should move all your custom functions to a module inside your `.ipython` directory. Since what I was doing was a simple function that returns the git branch and status for the current directory, I created a file called `gitprompt.py` and then I included the filename in the `exec_file` configuration option:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_files = [b'gitprompt.py']
```

All definitions in such files are placed into the user namespace. So now I can use it inside my prompt:

```
# Input prompt.  '\#' will be transformed to the prompt number
c.PromptManager.in_template = br'{color.Green}\# {color.LightBlue}~\u{color.Green}:\w{color.LightBlue} {git_branch_and_st} \$\n>>> '

# Continuation prompt.
c.PromptManager.in2_template = br'... '
```

Notice that in order for the function to behave as such (i.e called each time the prompt is printed) you need to use the `IPython.core.prompts.LazyEvaluation` class. You may use it as a decorator for your function. The `gitprompt.py` has being placed in the public domain as the gist: https://gist.github.com/2719419